# сохранить файл после его изменения в textarea

Tags: java, веб-программирование, файлы, java-ee, сервлеты

Как изменить пользовательский файл после того как его изменил сам пользователь в textarea?
Вот код сервлета, где выводится файл пользователя в textarea:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Change", urlPatterns = {"/Change"})
public class Change extends HttpServlet 
{
static String filenamefile, filename, jjj;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    HttpSession httpSession = req.getSession(true);
    filenamefile = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("filenamefile");
    filename = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("filename");
    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
    /*PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/home/zhuk/Downloads/"
            + "jj.txt", "UTF-8");*/
    pw.println("" +
            "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "<html>\n" +
            "    <head>\n" +
            "        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" +
            "        <title>Изменения страницы</title>\n" +
            "    </head>\n" +
            "    \n" +
            "    \n" +
            "    <body>\n" +
            "        <h3>\n" +
            "            Страница: "+filenamefile+"\n" +
            "        </h3>\n");
            pw.println("            <form action=\"SaveServlet\">");        
            pw.println("                <textarea cols=\"70\" rows=\"20\">");
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(filename), 
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
            {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    pw.println(line);
                    //jjj+=line;
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /*for(int i = 0; i < jjj.length(); i++)
            {
                writer.println(jjj);
            }*/

            pw.println(
            "            </textarea>\n" + 
            "            <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Сохранить\">" + 
            "        </form>\n" + 
            "    </body>\n" +
            "</html>");
            //writer.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что Вам необходимо реализовать логику на элементе textarea перед отправкой формы? Тогда Вам необходимо сделать отправку через кнопку и на нее повесить слушателя и в слушателе реализовать логику на JS.

Comment: @ezhov_da, все верно, так и нужно сделать, но как это реализовать так и не понял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализации, Вам необходимо:
1. Добавить кнопку, которая будет отправлять информацию:

```
    <center><button type="button" id="done" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button></center>
```

2. Добавить в выводимый текст в блок head объявление JS скрипта:

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           document.getElementById("done").addEventListener("click", function () {
               //ЗДЕСЬ ПОЛУЧАЕТЕ ВАШУ ТЕКСТОВУЮ ОБЛАСТЬ, ЕЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ И ИСПРАВЛЯЕТЕ КАК ХОТИТЕ

               $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: "ВАШ URL",
                   data: ВАШИ ДАННЫЕ,
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function (response) { //Если все нормально
                       ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ В СЛУЧАЕ УДАЧНОЙ ОТПРАВКИ И ОБРАБОТКИ
                   },
                   error: function (response) { //Если ошибка
                       ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ ЕСЛИ ОШИБКА
                   }
               });
           });
       });
   </script>
   ```

С необходимой Вам логикой.

Важно! Отправка запроса происходит через AJAX.

Comment: спасибо за помощь))